# SQL Server procedure that changes bit on if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have three stored procedures:

1. The first will insert a `userId` and `roleId`
2. The second will delete targeted `userId` and `roleId`
3. The third is an update that is supposed to change the bit value of column `isShopper`

The `userId` is unique, but can have multiple roles. The roles are "customer", "shopper", and "admin". When I insert the role of "shopper" the column `isShopper` has a bit value of 1, which is what I want.

However when I delete the role of "shopper" from the user, the bit value remains at 1. I'm curious how I would go about changing the bit value of shopper back to 0 when the shopper role is removed.

Insert procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert]
    @UserId nvarchar (128),
    @RoleId nvarchar (128)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] ([UserId], [RoleId])
        SELECT  
            @UserId, @RoleId
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS(SELECT UserId, RoleId
                       FROM AspNetUserRoles
                       WHERE RoleId = @RoleId
                         AND UserId = @UserId)

    EXECUTE dbo.ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update
                @UserId, @RoleId
END
```

Delete procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Asp_Net_User_Role_Delete]
    @UserId nvarchar (128),
    @RoleId nvarchar (128)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
    WHERE RoleId = @RoleId 
      AND UserId = @UserId

    EXECUTE dbo.ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update
            @UserId, @RoleId        
END
```

Update procedure (tagged on the end of the insert and delete)

```
ALTER proc dbo.ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update
    @IsShopper bit,
    @UserId nvarchar (128),
    @RoleId nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@RoleId = '91e67659-0dcb-4171-bc76-78d18b1d1336')
        AND @IsShopper = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[ProfileAccountInfos]
        SET [DateModified] = getutcdate(),
            [IsShopper] = 1
        WHERE UserId = @UserId
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In Procedure "ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update" you have parameter @IsShooper but you are not passing value for that parameter when you are executing from "Asp_Net_User_Role_Delete" or "Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert".

If your the RoleId value is going to be the same all the time then you can decide the value of @IsShopper in the `Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert` and `Asp_Net_User_Role_Delete` procedures and pass it to the `ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update` procedure. You don't need @RoleId parameter in `ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update` Procedure.

So `ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update` will be simplified as following.

```
ALTER proc dbo.ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update
    ,@UserId nvarchar (128)
    ,@IsShopper BIT
AS
 BEGIN

   UPDATE  [dbo].[ProfileAccountInfos] SET [DateModified] = getutcdate(),[IsShopper] = @IsShopper WHERE UserId = @UserI
 END
```

Procedure `Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert` will be changed as following.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert]
    @UserId nvarchar (128),
    @RoleId nvarchar (128)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IsShoper BIT

  SET @IsShopper = 0

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] ([UserId], [RoleId])
    SELECT  
        @UserId, @RoleId
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT UserId, RoleId
                   FROM AspNetUserRoles
                   WHERE RoleId = @RoleId
                     AND UserId = @UserId)

  IF (@RoleId = '91e67659-0dcb-4171-bc76-78d18b1d1336') -- If role being inserted is Shopper then mark user as a Shopper.
  BEGIN
      SET @IsShopper = 1
  END

  EXECUTE dbo.ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update @UserId, @IsShopper
END
```

Procedure `Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert` will be changed as following.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Asp_Net_User_Role_Delete]
    @UserId nvarchar (128),
    @RoleId nvarchar (128)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IsShoper BIT

  SET @IsShopper = 1

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] WHERE RoleId = @RoleId AND UserId = @UserId

  IF (@RoleId = '91e67659-0dcb-4171-bc76-78d18b1d1336') -- If role being deleted is Shopper then mark user as non-shopper.
  BEGIN
     SET @IsShopper = 0
  END

  EXECUTE dbo.ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update @UserId, @IsShopper        
END
```

You can also avoid having `ProfileAccountInfos_Shopper_Update` stored procedure. You can put the update statement in `Asp_Net_User_Role_Insert` and `Asp_Net_User_Role_Delete`

Comment: When using your answer I am successful inserting a new roleId and User Id; however when I use the delete proc both on columns, 'isShopping' does not return back to 0.

Comment: Ok.. got it... I missed the part of making it 0 when role is deleted. I think in that case the value of IsShopper should be decided in the insert and delete stored procedures and passed to update stored procedure. And updated stored procedure won't need `@RoleId` and If block. It will have `@IsShopper` parameter instead. I will update my answer soon.